# Fragment crash after selecting another item after onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-lists

This is a rather strange issue for me. I'm using a custom list to display my items and another fragment to display more of the selected item's data. However, whenever I press back and select another item, the app gives me an illegal exception error. What did I do wrong within my codes?
If I don't commit the transaction, the details fragment would not show.

This is my Events Fragment:

```
public static class EventsSectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        SharedPreferences settings = null;
        Editor editor;
        ListView list;
        TextView noEventsTv;

        public EventsSectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            recLifeCycle_with_savedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);

            list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            noEventsTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.norecordsTV);



            new GetEventsAsyncTask((MainActivity) getActivity()).execute(nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.SharedPreferences.getUserName(getActivity()));

            settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            return rootView;
        }

        public void updateEventList(final List<Event> eventList)
        {

            Log.i("updateEventList:eventlist.count", String.valueOf(eventList.size()));

            if (eventList.size() > 0) 
            {
                CustomList_Events adapter = new CustomList_Events(getActivity(), eventList);

                noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        event_id = "";
                        event_title = "";
                        event_desc = "";
                        start_date = "";
                        end_date = "";
                        start_time = "";
                        end_time = "";
                        picture_path = "";
                        location = "";

                        Event event = new Event();
                        event = eventList.get(position);
                        Log.i("Event_details", event.getEvent_id());

                        event_id = eventList.get(position).getEvent_id();
                        event_title = eventList.get(position).getEvent_title();
                        event_desc = eventList.get(position).getEvent_desc();
                        start_date = eventList.get(position).getStart_date();
                        end_date = eventList.get(position).getEnd_date();
                        start_time = eventList.get(position).getStart_time();
                        end_time = eventList.get(position).getEnd_time();
                        picture_path = eventList.get(position).getPicture_path();
                        location = eventList.get(position).getLocation();
                        // direct to event details fragment
                        startEventDetailsFragment();
                    }
                });
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.invalidateViews();
            } 
            else 
            {
                noEventsTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Here's the Details fragment:

```
public static class EventDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public EventDetailsFragment() {

    }

    ImageView banner;
    TextView e_title, e_loc, e_date, e_time, e_desc;
    String eventID;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        recLifeCycle_with_savedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_details, container, false);

        banner = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.banner_img);
        e_title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        e_loc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        e_date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        e_time = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        e_desc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.event_desc);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("event_id")) {
            eventID = args.getString("event_id");
            e_title.setText(args.getString("event_title"));
            e_desc.setText(args.getString("event_desc"));
            e_time.setText(args.getString("start_time") + " - " + args.getString("end_time"));
            e_date.setText(args.getString("start_date") + " - " + args.getString("end_date"));
            e_loc.setText(args.getString("event_location"));
            new GetImageAsyncTask(banner).execute(Constants.HOST_NAME + "/" + Constants.CMS_NAME + "/" + args.getString("pic_path"));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Then this is the method that passes the data over to the details fragment:

```
public static void startEventDetailsFragment() {
    EventDetailsFragment fragment = new EventDetailsFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("event_id", event_id);
    bundle.putString("event_title", event_title);
    bundle.putString("event_desc", event_desc);
    bundle.putString("start_time", start_time);
    bundle.putString("end_time", end_time);
    bundle.putString("start_date", start_date);
    bundle.putString("end_date", end_date);
    bundle.putString("event_location", location);
    bundle.putString("pic_path", picture_path);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transac = ft;
    transac.replace(R.id.fragment_events, fragment);
    transac.addToBackStack(null);
    transac.commit();
}
```

Here's the logcat:

```
10-17 01:54:01.494: I/Event_details(13856): EV00000018
10-17 01:54:01.494: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-17 01:54:01.514: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onStart
10-17 01:54:01.514: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onResume
10-17 01:54:01.544: D/dalvikvm(13856): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2108K, 17% free 10890K/13044K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
10-17 01:54:12.894: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onPause
10-17 01:54:12.894: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onStop
10-17 01:54:12.894: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onDestroyView
10-17 01:54:12.904: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onDestroy
10-17 01:54:12.904: I/MYTAG(13856): EventDetailsFragment.onDetach
10-17 01:54:17.294: I/Event_details(13856): EV00000007
10-17 01:54:17.294: D/AndroidRuntime(13856): Shutting down VM
10-17 01:54:17.294: W/dalvikvm(13856): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f9140)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856): Process: nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo, PID: 13856
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856): java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:582)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.MainActivity.startEventDetailsFragment(MainActivity.java:1882)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.MainActivity$EventsSectionFragment$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:752)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2947)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3681)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
10-17 01:54:17.304: E/AndroidRuntime(13856):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transac = ft;
```

looks like you have already call commit upon `ft`.

Change it with

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transac = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: If I change it to that, this is the error returned:
`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSupportFragmentManager() from the type FragmentActivity`

Comment: And this is my ft:
`static android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft;
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`